# Install swagger-ui error

Tags: docker, development-environment

I get the following errors when I run `docker build -t swagger-ui-builder`:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/connect/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/crc/lib/crc16_ccitt.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /build
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/connect/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/crc/lib/crc16_ccitt.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/connect/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/crc/lib/crc16_ccitt.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/repeating
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/semver/test/major-minor-patch.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /build
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/semver/test/major-minor-patch.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/semver/test/major-minor-patch.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/loud-rejection/node_modules/signal-exit/test/fixtures/parent.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /build
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/loud-rejection/node_modules/signal-exit/test/fixtures/parent.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/loud-rejection/node_modules/signal-exit/test/fixtures/parent.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, utime '/build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/redent/node_modules/indent-string/node_modules/repeating/node_modules/is-finite/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /build
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/redent/node_modules/indent-string/node_modules/repeating/node_modules/is-finite/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /build/node_modules/gulp-connect/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/redent/node_modules/indent-string/node_modules/repeating/node_modules/is-finite/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call utimes
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

I am using Mac OS X. I try to install swagger-ui to apply to our project. after I downloaded swagger-ui to my local and cd to swagger-ui folder and "run $ docker build -t swagger-ui-builder ." and I got so many errors above.

Comment: Hi David. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be much specific when you are posting a question. In this case, What  is the swagger-ui (link, git-repo-link)?, What version?, What you have done with it if any? Otherwise we cannot locate into your actual problem and find what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've found using [this pre-built image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sjeandeaux/docker-swagger-ui/) works pretty easy:

```
docker run -d --name swagguer-ui -p 8888:8888 sjeandeaux/docker-swagger-ui
```

Or with your own default API URL:

```
docker run -d --name swagger-ui -p 8888:8888 -e "API_URL=YOUR_URL" sjeandeaux/docker-swagger-ui
```